# Unable to use Regex for Client IDs while fetching JMX metrics for Kafka.consumer

Tags: java, regex, apache-kafka, jmx

I am following JM[X Monitoring Metrics available on Apache website](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring) for Kafka. 
One of the metrics is listed as following (notice the client id )

```
kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.w]+)
```

In my code I am using it in following way :

```
     args[2] = "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.w]+)";
args[3] = "records-lag-max"
        ObjectName oName = new ObjectName(args[2]);
                    try {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(mbeanConn.getAttribute(oName, args[3]));
                        } catch (AttributeNotFoundException | MBeanException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Error

> javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException:
>   kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.w]+)
>
> javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException:
>   kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.\w]+)

I am interested in getting the  **records-lag-max** which is as following :
**The maximum lag in terms of number of records for any partition in this window. An increasing value over time is your best indication that the consumer group is not keeping up with the producers**

Am I using the metric correctly or i need to loop on all client ids and fetch metrics individually??

Comment: Did you mean to use `([-.\\w]+)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think yes because thats  what I found it in docs .

Comment: So, does it mean `"kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.\\w]+)"` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it didnt worked - as you can see the error message

Comment: I only see `w`, not ``\\w`` in your question, hence my comment

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried \w too , please see my edit.  Apologies for last observation